# Floating a block of text near button with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How it is possible to have a floating block of text near button with Bootstrap ?

Here what I want:
[image]

Here the code I have a actually:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Submit</button>
        <div class="help-block">Datas not saved.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make this please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this CSS (by default `help-block` is block level element):

```
.help-block {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```